# bandwidth delay product of a given link

Tags: networking, tcp, delay, product, bandwidth

i have been reading online about bandwidth delay and i couldn't understand.

Bandwidth delay is the max amount of data that the pipe can 'store'

But given a packet of size L is to be send over a link (A to B) with transmission rate of K-bps and bandwidth delay of P bits.

does that mean that the time i will take to sent from A to be will be (L/P)/K ?

L/P because i can only sent this amount of bits every single time and (/K) because i take this long to sent that amount each time?

Answer (score 1):

Think of it like a garden hose.

Delay is the length. That determines how long it takes one drop to get from one end to the other.
Bandwidth is the cross-sectional area. That determines how many drops can travel together.

The product is volume, which corresponds to bandwidth-delay product, which corresponds to the total amount of water *in* the hose at any moment.

So if you have a full bucket of water and a funnel and you can pour it into the top of the hose, the total time for all the water to get to the other end is determined by

```
bucket capacity divided by volume
```

or

```
bucket capacity divided by (area multiplied by length)
```

or

```
bucket capacity divided by area divided by length
```

or

```
L/K/P
```

or

```
L/P/K
```

You can see that it doesn't matter which way around you do the divisions.